# How to Create a Table Only By CSS For several div tags?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 6 `<div>` tags and Have no access to Html of this page.So I try to create a table with css For these fields.

**Please See the attached Picture:**
[image: Picture-click here]

The Html codes is like this for every 4 fields:

**My HTML Codes are like following in my site :**

```
<div class="group">
<h3>
<span>title-group</span>
</h3>
<div class="field-1">
<div class="field-label">field-1</div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">11111111</div>
<div class="field-item odd">2222222222222222</div>
<div class="field-item even">333333333333</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-2">
<div class="field-label">field-2</div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">1111111111111111111111111</div>
<div class="field-item odd">22222222222222222222</div>
<div class="field-item even">333333333333333333333333333333333</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-3">
<div class="field-label">field-3</div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
<div class="field-item odd">222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
<div class="field-item even">3333333333333333333333333333333</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-4">
<div class="field-label">field-4</div>
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">
<span class="file">fiele</div>
<span class="file">fiele</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I Use css For float these tags and create a table , but every cell have different height for content,I want to have equal height for cells (field-item) . I Can add `height:100px;` but if content of A cell be more that 100px my table will destroy.I want to set height of **two fields on the right and left side equal with two fields on middle of table**.beacause content of these two middle fields are different wit differrent height.
My CSS thats used:

```
    .field {
  display: table;
}
.field-items {
  display: table-row;
}
.field-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.field-item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.field:first-child .field-item,
.field-items + .field-items .field-item {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**New picture after css addition:**

[image: **New Image - After editing css**]

Please Help me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a table, why do you not use the `table` tag instead of `div`?
But if you want to use `div` you can change the CSS to let it "be" a table

```css
.field-1 {
  display: table;
}
.field-items {
  display: table-row;
}
.field-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.field-item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.field-items:first-child .field-item {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-1">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">test</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf<br/> sdifgs</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update with 3 rows and columns

```css
.field {
  display: table;
}
.field-items {
  display: table-row;
}
.field-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.field-item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.field:first-child .field-item,
.field-items + .field-items .field-item {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">test</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf<br/> sdifgs</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">test</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf<br/> sdifgs</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item">test</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf<br/> sdifgs</div>
    <div class="field-item">testestsetse stsetset sets<br/> sdfsdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I said have not access to Html of page and can use css only.@UfguFugullu thanks, I test it.

Comment: this is my html code: ** <div class="field-1">
      <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item"></div>
            <div class="field-item"></div>
      </div></div>
<div class="field-2">
      <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item"></div>
            <div class="field-item"></div>
      </div></div>
<div class="field-3">
      <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item"></div>
            <div class="field-item"></div>
      </div></div> --- I have 3 <div> that must be 3 columns of my table.Help!!!

Comment: You should append this question on your first question and add some detailed informations whats wrong and what should be done @omiti

Comment: thank you vey very much,I edited my post and write new html codes and css with new picture for after of changes...your codes could not help me yet.whats the problem?

Comment: It seems that other styles overwrite the styles of the table. You have to show us all styles which effects the `tables` and I think you should learn some `CSS` basics

Comment: Can You Help me ? I'm waiting for your answer